# Reduce size of legend area in barplot

Tags: r, plot, legend

I can't reduce the size of the legend in this plot. Could someone help me out? I want it to appear topright, but with no more than 20% of the height of plot area

```
a <- c(3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2 )
barplot(a, beside = T,
col = 1:6, space = c(0, 2))
legend("topright", legend = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"), fill = 1:6, ncol = 2)
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The `cex` parameter will do that for you.

```
a <- c(3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2 )
barplot(a, beside = T,
        col = 1:6, space = c(0, 2))
legend("topright", 
       legend = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"), 
       fill = 1:6, ncol = 2,
       cex = 0.75)
```

[image: The plot]

Comment: when i cex=0.5 the size is good but the text is very small, how can i solve it?

Comment: @Cina I guess you should make `cex` a bit bigger then and then use `pt.cex` and `title.cex`. See the help for `legend` with `?legend`.