# Reducing Legend Size in R matplot

Tags: r, matplotlib

I was trying to create a chart using below code in R:

```
myplot<-function(data,rows,Colm){
  Data<-data[rows,Colm,drop=F]
  matplot(t(Data), type = "b", pch=15:18, col = c(1:4, 6))
  legend("bottomleft",inset = 0.01, legend = Players[rows],col = c(1:4, 6), 
pch=15:18, horiz = F)
}
myplot(Games)
```

and got the below plot:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNRCx.png)

Can anyone help me how to reduce the legend size?

Answer (score 0):

The answer can be found here: [Reduce size of legend area in barplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24361598/reduce-size-of-legend-area-in-barplot)

The key is the cex argument in the legend function call.

The default is the equivalent of 1. Larger than the default size is greater than 1. From your question, you probably want to put the value as .5 and experiment from there until it is the size you want.

Comment: Please do explain your answer!

Comment: I have added the third paragraph to expand. Is that the kind of explanation you meant?

Comment: Thank you @JustinInOz, cex = 0.4 worked.

Comment: If you would be so kind as to mark the answer as accepted, that would be grand.